# highcharts column stack label

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I want to show a stacklabel with data coming from a json file, something similar to this.
http://jsfiddle.net/prJjY/183/

my code...

```
 yAxis: {
            title: {text:'%'},
            stackLabels: {
                style: {color: 'black'},
                enabled:true,
                formatter: function() {
                    console.log(this.axis.series[0].data);
                    return (this.axis.series[0].yData[this.y]) + '%';
                }

            }},
```

and my json file...

```
[{"y":4.2,"z":"0412","stack":"10a","color":"red"}...
```

It's a simple doubt. When I console series.data , it shows all the objects in json. 
I need to get the 'this' data something like.

```
this.axis.series[0].data[this].stack);
```

but this don't work, if I put 0 instead this,

```
    this.axis.series[0].data[0]  
//it works (without stack part) with stack part i got a '...data[0] is undefined'
```

In this way I'll get always data from zero object.

What is missing to my code work?

After the first answer I did this ...

var temp = this.axis.series[0].data[this.x];

```
for(var propertyName in temp) {
     console.log(temp["stacko"]); //inside the for it works
;}
console.log(temp["stacko"]); //outside the for I get Undefined
```

Why? :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is you are using `this` as reference but you should use `this.x` instead:

```
this.axis.series[0].data[this.x].stack);
```

Comment: thanks, first problem is solved with this.x, but still occurring the same problem that occurs with data[0], when I add ".stack" I get a "data[this.x] is undefined"

Comment: Could you recreate second issue on jsFiddle, please? Thanks!

Comment: I create this Fiddle based on the example, but the for in the fiddle don't work, in my pc work, http://jsfiddle.net/jonsnowx/j6ntL/, at least is possible to get the idea

Comment: the answer is get the attr by another way. adding "options"

this.axis.series[0].options.data[this.x].stack;

thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

Even though Pawel Fus's answer should work, it turns out that you have to go through options to get to the data..

like so,

```
this.axis.series[0].options.data[this.x].stack
```